# WSL distribution networking only when version set to 1

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

In Windows 11, I needed WSL 2 to have a distribution with systemd, so I installed both.
It opened without problem, but it had no internet.

I guess the problem is not related to DNS because it also occurs with things like `ping 8.8.8.8` or ping to the 'distribution' ip itself `ping 172.x.xxx.x` (as seen in the windows side with `ipconfig /all`).

This post is similar to:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5336
If I transform the installed Ubuntu distribution to WSL 1, with `wsl --set-version Ubuntu 1`, internet and ping works perfectly (but I need wsl2 systemd). I followed suggestions (see EDIT) of more than 10 different pages, but nothing worked.
Those were related to changes in `/etc/resolv.conf`, Firewall, VPN, Hyper-V and WSL feature reinstalling, swap disabling/compression, temp folder compression, IPv6 disabling, changing router, etc. The github post has around 200 comments, I think I have tried all answers contained in them.

As soon as I transform back to version 2, remote, or local ping to the WSL IP itself (172.XX.XXX.X), breaks.

Any suggestion?

EDIT: My Firewall was inactivated but not uninstalled, see answer.

Comment: Feels like I've seen this _exact_ post a month ago… Do you have any antivirus software with its own "firewall" active? Or a VPN app with a "killswitch"?

Comment: I disabled firewalls, no vpn

Comment: Are you connected through a VPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing, which worked, was resetting Windows (keeping personal files - losing all apps).

In order to have `systemd` working, provided only by WSL 2, it was necessary to have the WSL from Microsoft Store installed [(see AskUbuntu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379425/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1-cant-operate#answer-1379567)

While reinstalling my apps, I noticed a total correlation of having the ZoneAlarm Antivirus, Firewall installed with lack of internet in WSL2 Ubuntu. Weird fact is that having that Antivirus and Firewall Inactive also impeded the connection of WSL. So, a total Uninstall of ZA was necessary. Replicating the problem is easy, because the connection is restored immediately after uninstalling, and lost immediately upon installing (inactive or not).

The version of ZA is 4.0.148.0 (ZA) or 4.000.0148 (according to Windows)